# OPEN PYXL V PANDAS v Other?

Tags: excel, pandas, csv, xlsx, openpyxl

I am wanting to read from a csv and write that to an excel [Large amount of dynamic data]
I have learnt that the best library for this is openpyxl or Pandas.  What is the better option
I am currently using VBA however I am wanting it to be faster and not have to open every single excel file and use tonnes of cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl is good for every day use, though Pandas is more popular and for good reason as it performs fast
My recommendation: xlwings.  It's the fastest for large data